# google.maps.event.trigger for dragend doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, drag-and-drop

for some reason, the dragend trigger for the google maps doesn't work for me. see code lines 140-143 at http://jsfiddle.net/wzcst/399/

```
google.maps.event.trigger(markerA, 'dragend', function() {
    latLngA = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
    noteA.text(bounds.contains(latLngA));
});
```

what i'm trying to accomplish is to update marker A depending on the location being inputted into the geocorder form field. for example: try 'pittsburg, kansas' in the form field. it should reposition marker A there but it doesn't.

any thoughts?

Comment: Where does results[0].geometry.location come from? That isn't the current location of markerA (even if the marker started there, if it was dragged, it would no longer be there).  I would expect its current location to be markerA.getPosition().

Comment: Also, if you want to detect when a marker is inside a circle, you don't want to use circle.getBounds(), that returns a rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

The code is confused between triggering an event and adding a listener function. However, I suspect what you want is simply to set the position of the marker:

```
markerA.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
```

To trigger a dragend event, you'd pass a MouseEvent and not a function, although I can't think of a reason to ever use this:

```
var mouseEvent1 = {
  stop: null,
  latLng: results[0].geometry.location
}
google.maps.event.trigger(markerA, 'dragend', mouseEvent1);
```